# addError Message on Lead conversion

Tags: apex, trigger

Got a requirement,which i have handled through trigger but want to know a better approach to this & an issue i see on a converted leads.Please suggest

Requirement is: When you convert a lead to account,on convert page if you add details to create an activity before clicking convert button.Need a check for a custom field on that activity to have a value  for certain category of lead/account.So in case user creates an activity during lead conversion without putting a value for this field then user should be shown a message on UI to populate this.
I can't make this as required, as only for certain category of lead and account this custom field needs to be required one. As this is on activity,sales force has many limitation- i can't create a lookup nor i can use validation rule.

Issue seen is: The addError doesn't show a message on UI,when activity gets created using the convert button.It just simply converts it to account -- no message ---no activity..
In the trigger,i am checking for the 'related to' field/What Id/Who id and depending on that doing a check to show the message-but it doesnt work.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. When is the activity being created? What is the custom field and the options for it? Without that context it's difficult to provide an answer. Are you wanting to run the trigger on new activities related to leads? If you have a class that runs as part of lead conversion, you can always have it check for related activities to the lead and depending on the value in the field, change the open activity's "related to". Is that also part of what you're wanting to do?

Comment: @crmprogdev: Activity is created during the conversion of lead, and this activity doesn't exist on the lead before. I want to run the trigger on the activity created as part of conversion onto account and its contact.  To give example:  Create a lead without task,then when u convert it to account: on the conversion page enter the task detail expect to be seen on the converted account and contact. I want to put the required validation message on UI in this convert page-before the lead converts to account & contact..(or rather when convert button is clicked).

Comment: have you enabled workflows/triggers for lead conversion in Lead Settings?

Comment: If @crop1645 suggestion to enable workflows/triggers for lead conversion doesn't solve your issue, I'd recommend creating a visual flow for your lead conversion which would allow you to create the error message in the UI as part of the flow.

Comment: @crmprogdev: yes i have enabled it but it doesnt throw a message, let me try the visual flow way: and check.Thanks